# Change the size of subplot so histogram and heatmap x-axes lineup

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am attempting to plot three graphs (histogram, heatmap, and heatmap) on a single row using `seaborn`. I was able to produce all three graphs with the desired formatting, however, the x-axes of the three graphs are not aligned, which is shown below. I have also included the code I used to generate the figure.

It appears this is an effect of using the `square=True` option for the heatmaps which results in them not using the full plotting space. How do I change the plotting (subplot) size of the histogram so that the all three x-axes are aligned? Is there a way to change the size of one of the subplots? If I have to define the size of each subplot is there a way to determine the size required to have all x-axes aligned?
 [image: Example Figure]

```
style = dict(size=14, color='black')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4), ncols=3, nrows=1)
left   =  0.125  # the left side of the subplots of the figure
right  =  0.9    # the right side of the subplots of the figure
bottom =  0.1    # the bottom of the subplots of the figure
top    =  1    # the top of the subplots of the figure
wspace =  1     # the amount of width reserved for blank space between subplots
hspace =  0   # the amount of height reserved for white space between subplots

# This function actually adjusts the sub plots using the above paramters
plt.subplots_adjust(
    left    =  left, 
    bottom  =  bottom, 
    right   =  right, 
    top     =  top, 
    wspace  =  wspace, 
    hspace  =  hspace
)

boots = np.random.exponential(size=100000)
colors = sns.color_palette("colorblind")
ax[0] = sns.distplot(boots, kde=False, bins=20, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].axvline(x=0.8673, color=colors[1], linestyle = '--')
ax[0].axvline(x=.22, color="black", linestyle = "--")
ax[0].tick_params(labelsize = "13")
ax[0].set_xlabel("Average accuracy",fontsize=13)
ax[0].set_ylabel("Permutations", fontsize=13)

ax[1] = sns.heatmap(cf_matrices['CYANO-MLP'], vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Blues", square=True,
            linewidths=0.1, linecolor = "grey", ax=ax[1], 
                 cbar_kws={ 
                           'label': 'Mean Proportion\nClade Assignment',
                           'use_gridspec': False, 'location': "top",
                           "shrink": 1.2})
ax[1].tick_params(labelsize=13)
ax[1].text(8.2, 0.7, "N=11", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 1.7, "N=27", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 2.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 3.7, "N=29", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 4.7, "N=3", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 5.7, "N=5", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 6.7, "N=4", **style)
ax[1].text(8.2, 7.7, "N=4", **style)
ax[1].figure.axes[-1].xaxis.label.set_size(13)
plt.setp(ax[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=60)
ax[1].set_xlabel("Predicted Clade", size=15)
ax[1].set_ylabel("True Clade", size=15)

ax[2] = sns.heatmap(cf_matrices['CYANO-MLP-BAL'], vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Blues", square=True,
            linewidths=0.1, linecolor = "grey", ax=ax[2], 
                 cbar_kws={ 
                           'label': 'Mean Proportion\nClade Assignment',
                           'use_gridspec': False, 'location': "top",
                           "shrink": 1.2})
ax[2].tick_params(labelsize=13)
ax[2].text(8.2, 0.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 1.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 2.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 3.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 4.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 5.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 6.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].text(8.2, 7.7, "N=30", **style)
ax[2].figure.axes[-1].xaxis.label.set_size(13)
plt.setp(ax[2].get_xticklabels(), rotation=60)
ax[2].set_xlabel("Predicted Clade", size=15)
ax[2].set_ylabel("True Clade", size=15)
sns.despine(ax=ax[0])
```

Comment: Try `bottom  =  0.3`, `top = 0.7` or similar.

Comment: A general comment is that it is important to post only minimal, reproducible, working examples. This usually increases the likeliness of good answers, but also provides a good reference for others to use.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Worked perfectly. If you want to submit it as an answer I will accept it.